# ReportViewer v11.0.0.0 Runtime Error during excel export

Tags: reportviewer, httpruntime

I'm running into a Runtime error when I try to export a report to excel in ReportViewer that goes beyond 110 seconds.

The only solution to this problem that has worked, which I have found on here and numerous other sites, was setting the executionTimeout under httpRuntime in the root web.config file.

Now while this does work it isn't ideal for the project and it would be preferable if only the ReportViewer had a longer runtime timeout.

My question then is there any way to have a executionTimeout set for only the ReportViewer?

**Things I've tried that still timeout**

Applying an executionTimeout to the area where the ReportViewer is located in the root web.config

```
<location path="Areas/Reporting">
    <system.web>
      <httpRuntime executionTimeout="600" maxRequestLength="2097151"/>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Setting the following timeouts in the code behind of the ReportViewer

```
Server.ScriptTimeout = 600;
ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).AsyncPostBackTimeout = 600;

if (!IsPostBack)
                {
reportViewer.ServerReport.Timeout = reportViewerServerReportTimeoutMilliseconds;
```